# Dimension of gamma matrices in higher dimensional Dirac equations

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, spinors

Reading about Dirac's equation in higher dimensional space-times I have read that the [gamma matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-dimensional_gamma_matrices) are $2^{[D/2]}\times{}2^{[D/2]}$.

So, if we have $D=11$, for example, how is this formula supposed to be understood?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53318/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand it as rounded down. For example, in $D = 3$, you should have $2^1\times 2^1$ matrices. Indeed in $D = 3$ the Dirac matrices are the familiar Pauli matrices. $$
\sigma_1 = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
 \quad
 \sigma_2 = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -i \\
  i & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}
 \quad
 \sigma_3 = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & -1
 \end{pmatrix}$$
    (you can verify that they satisfy the anticommutation relation required with respect to the Euclidean metric).

Comment: How is 2+3/2= 3.5 rounded down 1?

Comment: The $+2$  shouldn't be there. Surely in $3+1$ dimensions we do not have $16\times 16$ Dirac matrices.