# Solution to Dirac equation

Tags: representation-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

We take the solution of Dirac equation as 4 component wave function (Dirac Spinor). But how do we know that it can't be a square or rectangular matrix like 4x2 or 4x4 matrix?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53318/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

It is a question of degrees of freedom. A solution to Dirac equation with 1$\times$4 components has precisely enough freedom for describing a single (without any "internal" quantum numbers) Dirac fermion which has only two states with different spin orientations. However, if your fermion field has additional quantum numbers (like color charge in strong interactions), the wavefunction really could be thought of as a matrix as you suggested (and if there are several quantum numbers, it will become a multidimensional array). But it's completely the same description as just writing a set of equations for each of 1$\times$4 wavefunctions corresponding to fermions with particular quantum numbers.