# Is this interpretation of fermionic dimensions correct?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions, grassmann-numbers, superspace-formalism

The number of Grassmann coordinates in ${\cal N}=1$, $3+1$ dimensional superspace is $4$. Let's call them:
$\theta_1$ $\theta_2$ $\theta_3$ $\theta_4$.

The Grassmann variables can be represented by analogy with the matrix representation of complex numbers by $2^n\times2^n$ matrices where $n$ is the number of Grassmann variables.

For example for $n=2$ one can write:

\begin{equation*}
\theta_1= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\theta_2= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 &-1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

My question is: if Grassmann numbers can be represented on $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$ the same way that complex numbers are represented on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? I'm not sure if $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$ would be the minimum dimension needed for a global embedding, in case. But locally I ***assume*** it's the minimum dimension needed.

I know that Grassmann numbers do not make up a field and the analogy fails. But still, I want to know if such a geometrical embedding works out.

I mean, can it be interpreted that spacetime must be $20$ dimensional in principle but $16$ dimensions of it are constrained by Grassmann's algebra(given a specific algebraic structure)?

I know that it might sound stupid, but even something close to such an interpretation or a relation between different types of dimensions(fermionic, bosonic, both compact or large) can really help.

Comment: Calabi-Yaus of complex dimension 3 are used in compactifications of the super string, not bosonic string. Also the size of the matrix you need to represent Grassman numbers is only 2 to the number of supercharges when you have *a single superfield*. Consider a two point function like $\left < \Phi(x_1, \theta_1) \Phi(x_2, \theta_2) \right >$. Now, all of a sudden you need $2^8$ instead of $2^4$.

Comment: I really do not understand the final part of your comment, as any function od Grassmann numbers, in most general case scenarios can be expanded in terms of a unique basis which is 16 dimensional in the case of ${\cal N}=1$ @ConnorBehan

Comment: I'm not sure what the question here is. The question first states (correctly) that Graßmann algebras with $n$ generators have representations as $2^n$-by-$2^n$ matrices. It then suddenly switches to talking about $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (not $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$!) - why? Where does the idea that "spacetime must be 20 dimensional" come from? What does it mean for a dimension to be "constrained by Graßmann's algebra"?

Comment: I fixed the blunder. About the meaning of containing the extra dimensions, I mean what we actually do to complex numbers. A complex number can be represented on the $\mathbb{R^2}$. Differentitation in complex plane is for instance, a specific case of differentitation on real plane. In other words the complex analysis is a specific case of real analysis. The same by analogy applies to grassmann analysis. It's a constrained form of real analysis on 16 real dimensions. @ACuriousMind

Comment: That is not true - the complex numbers are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a real vector space, hence they indeed represent 2 real dimensions. That the Graßmann numbers have a minimal representation as a subalgebra of $\mathrm{Mat}(\mathbb{R}^{2^n})$ doesn't imply they're isomorphic as a vector space to $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$ - rather, they are by definition isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a vector space because they are an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra with $n$ generators.

Comment: "...minimal representation as a subalgebra of $Mat(\mathbb{R^n})$"
What does this mean? @ACuriousMind

Comment: I mean that there is no smaller $m$ for which there is a subalgebra of $\mathbb{R}^m$-by-$\mathbb{R}^m$ matrices that is isomorphic to the Graßmann algebra. In plainer terms, there are no smaller matrices that have the same (anti-)commutation relations.

Comment: @ACuriousMind is there any easy way that such isomorphism is nonexistent?

Comment: My point was that for a function of $n$ complex variables, the number of real numbers you need is linear in $n$. But for a function of $n$ $\mathcal{N} = 1$ Grassman varaibles, this number is exponential in $n$.

Comment: A multi-variable function of Grassmann variables does not necessarily have to be represented as a subset of a higher number system.
For example in the case of multi-variable complex functions, the function maps two complex numbers to a doublet like $(a,b)| a,b\in \mathbb{C^2}$ or one can prefer to represent the same doublet in more complex number system which is that of quaternions. Again the rate of dimensional increase is exponential! $2^1$ then $2^2$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1917093/530905 @ConnorBehan

Comment: Your $2^1 \to 2^2$ could've been written $2 \cdot 1 \to 2 \cdot 2$. A function of 3 complex variables is a function of 3 real variables... not 8.

Comment: Yes, but still I can not make sense of your first comment when it says the dimension of the grassmann numbers shoud increase

Comment: Suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are 4 component Grassman numbers. 16 by 16 matrices are enough to satisfy $\alpha_i \alpha_j = -\alpha_j \alpha_i$ and $\beta_i \beta_j = -\beta_j \beta_i$ individually. But they are not enough to also satisfy $\alpha_i \beta_j = -\beta_j \alpha_i$. (Also, I said "3 real variables" above when I meant 6).

Comment: Ok. But honestly do not know why $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ should anticommute. They should anticommute if and  only if there are 8 supercharges and not 4. My expectation is that computing a two point function should not change the number of generators of algebra. @ConnorBehan

Comment: If you could share some physics student friendly analysis of such problem by an author, maybe It helps me understand your point in case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140779/discussion-between-connor-behan-and-bastam-tajik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That the Graßmann algebra has a representation as $2^n$ by $2^n$ matrices does not imply that it represents $2^n$ dimensions. The reason complex numbers correspond to two real dimensions is that the complex numbers are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a vector space over the real numbers. The Graßmann algebra on $n$ generators actually *does* have dimension $2^n$ as a real vector space because the space of $k$ products of the generators [has dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Basis_and_dimension) $\binom{n}{k}$ and so the full algebra has dimension $\sum_k \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$, but this not a direct consequence of the representation being matrices over $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$ - note that the space of all matrices of that size has dimension $(2^n)^2$.
2. The representation as $2^n$ by $2^n$ matrices is the unique irreducible representation of a Graßmann algebra on $n$ generators because the Graßmann algebra is related to a Euclidean Clifford algebra of $2n$ $\gamma$-matrices by
   $$ \theta_i = \frac{1}{2}(\gamma_i -\mathrm{i}\gamma_{N+i})$$
   and the unique irreducible representation of $2N$ $\gamma$-matrices is $2^n$-dimensional, see [this answer by Qmechanic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/53472/50583). Note that you can obtain the $\gamma$-matrices from the $\theta_i$ as $\theta_i\pm\theta_i^\dagger$ since the Euclidean $\gamma_i$ can be chosen Hermitian, so this representation of the Graßmann algebra is also unique.
3. For [supermanifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermanifold), we usually do not use the notion of dimension as a single number, since the very different nature of bosonic and fermionic coordinates makes it rather useless to try and lump both of them into a single number. Instead one thinks of the bosonic and fermionic coordinates separately, saying that a supermanifold that is locally $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $m$ Graßmann coordinates attached has a dimension of $(n,m)$. The whole point of the fermionic coordinates is that they carry a very different kind of information than just being a list of real-valued numbers - the isomorphism as vector spaces to $\mathbb{R}^{n+2^m}$ ignores the whole algebra structure of the Graßmann numbers, and so forgets an essential structure. No one will accept calling this a manifold of dimension $n+2^m$ because that is just not a useful way to look at it - you've explicitly dropped the very thing that *distinguishes* a supermanifold from a manifold.

Comment: Here you endorse that such isomorphism is existent but not beautiful to think of it this way. right?

Comment: @BastamTajik It's more that the isomorphism *exists* in terms of vector spaces, but the thing we actually care about is the *algebra* structure (the multiplication $\theta_i\theta_j$) and $\mathbb{R}^n$ in general does not have such a structure. This isn't an aesthetic thing ("beautiful" vs "ugly"), it's a matter of why we're using the structure in the first place ("useful" vs "useless").

Comment: ok, it's useless but correct. that's my real concern.