# What is the smallest possible dimension to represent $N$ operators $O_i$ with $\{O_i, O_j \} = 2 \delta_{ij}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, fermions, clifford-algebra

The question is in the title. I have an algebra of Hermitian operators that satisfy:
\begin{align}
\{O_i, O_j\} = 2 \delta_{ij}
\end{align}
that means all of those operators have eigenvalues $\pm 1$, and I'm looking for a way to represent those operators. Because of the anticommutation, none of the operators can share an eigenbasis: If $|+, i\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $O_i$, then
\begin{align}
O_j O_i |+, i\rangle = O_j |+, i \rangle = ( O_j |+, i \rangle)
\end{align}

But also:

\begin{align}
O_j O_i |+, i\rangle = - O_i O_j |+, i\rangle = - O_i (O_j |+, i\rangle)
\end{align}
That means $O_j |+, i\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $O_i$ with eigenvalue $-1$. The action of any $O_j$ on an eigenvector of $O_i$ is turning it to an eigenvector of $O_i$ with the negative eigenvalue.

I find this particular system represented with the $O_i$ being the pauli matrices, acting on a two dimensional system, here we have 3 observables, acting on a two dimensional system. If I have $N$ observables, can I find (at least with certain $N$) a minimum of dimensions that is required?

To ask the reverse question: For a 2-state system, I can't have a fourth spin operator, which satisfies the same relations as the other two - 3 seems to be the maximum number of operators. Is there a general rule to that, for systems of higher dimensionality?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Dimension of Dirac $\gamma$ matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53318/2451)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer  $d= 2^{\lfloor N/2\rfloor}$ is found  in many books as an application of fermionic Fock spaces and also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-dimensional_gamma_matrices) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%E2%80%93Brauer_matrices). I would give a more detailed account, but this sounds like a homewok question.

Comment: Perhaps you can expand the answer (e.g. give an explicit reference or be more detailed here)...

Comment: Aren't the mentioned pauli matrices $\sigma_i$ already a counter example? 3 of them satisfy the mentioned relation, the dimension should then be not 2, but $2^{1,5}$.

Comment: The floor function $\lfloor x \rfloor$ means the integer part, so $\lfloor 1.5 \rfloor=1$.

Comment: @obias Fünke I would, but I suspect that this is a homework problem.

Comment: @mikestone it is not. I try to get a deeper understanding of the the structure of hilbert spaces that represent such an operator algebra as the one mentioned, and trying to find the minimum number of base states / or alternatively the maximum number of observables seemed like a good starting point.

Comment: I suggest, then, that you look at my arxiv paper arXiv:2009.00518 as an entry to the literature. Section two lays out the standard construction of the gamma matrices.