Characterization of Pauli Spin Matrices
Say I have a finite collection $\{O_i\}_{i=1}^{d}$ of traceless, mutually orthogonal, dichotomic (meaning eigenvalues are $\pm 1$) observables satisfying the anti-commutation relations $\{O_i,O_j\}=2\delta_{ij}I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Assuming $d>2$, are these enough conditions to conclude that the algebra spanned by $\{O_i\}_{i=1}^{d}$ is isomorphic to the algebra spanned by the Pauli spin matrices? If not, what further conditions are needed to draw such a conclusion?
By the way, this is not a homework problem. I have come across such a collection of observables in my research, and am hoping to conclude that the algebra spanned by these observables is necessarily isomorphic to the algebra spanned by the Pauli spin matrices.

@ApoorvPotnis I am not assuming these are the Pauli spin matrices. I am trying to deduce this from the given assumptions.

Wait, I read it as a commutator instead of an anti commutator. My bad

Hint: take d=4 and look at direct sums of Paulis.

You know that changes of basis exist right?

@ConnorBehan I re-edited the question back to its original form, where it is asked if the algebra spanned by these observables is isomorphic to the algebra spanned by the Pauli spin matrices.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/737830/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53318/2451
