# Is the solution of the Dirac equation supposed to be a $4\times 4$ matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

Rearranging the Dirac Equation, we find that
$$\sum_\mu\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi = -imc\frac{2\pi}{h} \psi.$$
It appears that the wavefunction times the constant is equal to the matrix result of the summation on the left hand side of the equation.

Am I doing something wrong? Keep in mind that I'm going off of little more than my knowledge of differential equations and matrices, as I do not have access to formal education in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Hi Alexandra, you can find a MathJax tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Related: [Dimension of Dirac $\gamma$ matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53318/2451).

Comment: *I don't know how to use symbols on this site.* When you wrote your question, a link to the MathJax tutorial was in Step 1 of the instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Your rearranged Dirac equation is
$$\sum_\mu\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi = -imc\frac{2\pi}{h} \psi.$$

For this to make sense $\psi$ needs to be $4\times 1$ matrix,
i.e. a column vector.
Then you have a column vector on both sides of the equation.

To understand this, remember the definition of [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).
Multiplying a $4\times 4$ matrix with a $4\times 1$ matrix will give
a $4\times 1$ matrix. For example:
$$\gamma^0\partial_0 \psi
=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&-1&0\\ 0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}
\partial_0
\begin{pmatrix}\psi_1\\ \psi_2\\ \psi_3\\ \psi_4\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_0\psi_1\\ \partial_0\psi_2\\ -\partial_0\psi_3\\ -\partial_0\psi_4
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation you describe is
$$\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi = -\frac{imc}{\hbar} \psi$$

where $\hbar \equiv h/2\pi$. The gamma matrices are $4\times 4$ matrices, and the solution $\psi$ is a $4\times 1$ matrix, i.e. a column vector.

In case you are confused by the summation notation, the expanded equation is
$$\gamma^0 \partial_0\psi + \gamma^1\partial_1\psi + \gamma^2\partial_2\psi + \gamma^3\partial_3\psi  = -\frac{imc}{\hbar}\psi$$

Comment: But how can psi be a column vector, if the gamma matrix each derivative is multiplied by is 4x4? Is it a column vector of matrices?

Comment: @Alexandra You might be getting tripped up by the summation notation. For each index $\mu\in[0,1,2,3]$, $\partial_\mu\psi$ is a column vector and $\gamma^\mu$ is a matrix which acts on it via standard matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Alexandra Search term: [Einstein summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Comment: When you multiply a column vector by a matrix, the results is a column vector.