# Clifford Algebra in 3D

Tags: group-representations, representation-theory, spacetime-dimensions, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

Why the gamma matrices are taken 2 by 2 (Pauli matrices) in 3 dimensional Clifford Algebra. As in 4D Clifford Algebra the matrices are 4 by 4, in 3D Algebra why are they not 3 by 3 matrices? The question can be asked another way that should we use the representation according to the components of Dirac spinor?

Comment: How do you know such a representation does not exist? A clifford algebra describes *any* objects that obey the laws of the algebra--whether they're matrices or some other mathematical objects with some product operation.

Comment: I understand your argument. I am studying Dirac equation in 2+1 D, I think the reason to take gamma matrices 2 by 2 in my case is that the Dirac spinor is two component here. I want to know that if there is any other reason also?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53318/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259514/2451 ,  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41282/2451 and links therein.

Comment: #Qmechanic it was helpful, thanx.